dell inspirion 5548 fan remains stuck on max speed when on battery power
I have a DELL inspirion 5548 laptop, and on all (x)ubuntu versions i used 18.04 LTS - 24.04 LTS i have the following situation: if the CPU gets high load (e.g. i successively open multiple youtube tabs w/o waiting for each of them to finish loading) then the fan kicks in at max speed; then, once the tabs complete loading the CPU load drops and:

on external power, the fan  slows down and then stops spinning completely (as expected)
ON BATTERY, THE FAN REMAINS STUCK AT MAX SPEED; if i then plug in the external power the fan stops

One more remark: if the CPU load does not get too high (e.g. i just open a new youtube tab instead of many) then the fan speed increases (it's a pretty old dual-core i5 after all) but does not get to spin very fast, and in this case (when the fan did not go to very high speed or max out) the fan properly stops spinning both on external power AND on battery when the CPU load drops (in other words, the prob with the fan not stopping when on battery only happens if the fan has reached very high/max speed)
Does anyone know a fix to this problem?
